# Someone tagged me in comment, but I's not notified

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications

I'm talking about [this comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116185/wp-admin-redirecting-to-wp-login-php#comment163548_116185), where the MagentoBoy tagged me in his comment. But I found no Notification:
[image]

In this image, the lowest notification was of 2 days ago, while the comment I'm saying about is of 2 hours ago.

Answer (score 6):

As per [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

> Single trailing punctuation such as a dot, comma or colon is ignored, like *@name, yes* works, but *@name... no* does not.